# AsusPro P5540U - Wifi Working but Shows as Unavailable

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 server + GNOME Desktop layered on it, here is the order of my installation

- Installed Ubuntu server 20.04.
- During installation, wifi was detected and I connected to Wifi Network.
- Installation completed successfully and I also installed `sudo install ubuntu-desktop`.

**Issue**: After desktop installed and was able to boot into the desktop environment, wifi was still connected, but it does not show the WiFi network name nor does it allow me to switch the WiFi network connection.

`lspci -v` results shows:

> Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
> Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
> Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 140
> Memory at ef200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
> Capabilities: 
> Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
> Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Looking at the result above, it seems the **access denied** value on the capabilities line might be the issue, some clarity will be appreciate as to changing the **capabilities** status.

I am able to browse using the WiFi but I cannot see the WiFi connection or switch, because what you see in the WiFi settings is **unavailable**

Kindly help with any clues.?[image]

Regards.

For `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`, here is the screenshot of the output below:
[image]

Comment: If you installed the server version and later added Desktop, I assume that networking is still being controlled by netplan rather than Network Manager. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Please redact any passwords.

Comment: `(base) samuelson@syncserve:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
cat: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml: Permission denied
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
`

Comment: I have updated the quested with the sudo-ed output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you back up the current yaml file. First, find it's exact name:

```
ls /etc/netplan/
```

Next:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/<name_you_found>.yaml /etc/netplan/<name_you_found>.bak
```

Write a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Write the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very strict about spacing and indentation; proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x). Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot. All interfaces should now be available in Network Manager.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. 

I still regard myself a newbie with Linux, I just switched to Ubuntu as my everyday OS last year November, been a Windows Server Admin for more than 10yrs, doing Linux Admin onece a while because of cloud service administration tasks.

Comment: As a windows admin, the troubleshooting pattern is not really complex, I would really like to know how to troubleshoot linux OS and server issues deeply in a structure manner. What do you advise, is it just about fixing issues gradually like this.? or is there a better approach.?

Comment: Please meet me in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139115/discussion-between-samuel-obosa-and-chili555